# SSAS Tabular 1400 Project stuck on "Validating credentials"

Tags: ssas, powerquery, ssas-tabular

I'm implementing a tabular database in SQL Server Analysis Services using compatibility mode 1400. I started the development using integrated workspace, later, due to business demands, I had to switch to an external workspace database. I've had no problem in the process, and I could continue developments with almost no hassle.
Today, unfortunaley, when I try to process the workspace database from SSDT, the process starts, but it gets stuck on "operation in progress, validating credentials".

Have anyone experienced this? Can anyone point me in the right direction to investigate this problem?

I'm using version 2.5 of Analysis Services Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the 2.5 version of Analysis Services Project suffers for this problem. A simple update should fix the problem.